# How to select values from dynamic drop down using selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, dynamicdata

**My code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\Work\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/")
print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".fsw_inputField").click()  # Generating CSS from class name   
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[placeholder='From']").send_keys("chan")
cities = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p[class*='blackText']")
for city in cities:
    print(city.text)
    if city.text == "Chania, Greece":
        city.click()
```

**Console Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Work/Python/FirstDemo/PythonSelenium/dyncamicDropdown.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(city.text)
  File "D:\Work\Python\FirstDemo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 76, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "D:\Work\Python\FirstDemo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "D:\Work\Python\FirstDemo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Work\Python\FirstDemo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

Comment: You should wait until the DOM is completely loaded. And is the element is in focus when you try to click?? If it is not in focus also you may get the Stale Element Exception.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer could help in making sure the elements are loaded properly. But the actual issue in your code is that you are not breaking the for loop after **city.click()**

So,

1. You click dropdown
2. You click city
3. Dropdown closes
4. For loop still continues and tries to iterate through stale objects

SO the fix:

```
if city.text == "Chania, Greece":
    city.click()
    break
```

**Note:**  Added time.sleep() for waiting until the suggestions are loaded properly. You could use an explicit wait.

**Final code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\Work\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/")
print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".fsw_inputField").click()  # Generating CSS from class name   
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[placeholder='From']").send_keys("chan")
time.sleep(3);
cities = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p[class*='blackText']")
for city in cities:
    print(city.text)
    if city.text == "Chania, Greece":
        city.click()
        break
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Fair point but I still get an StaleElementReferenceException when trying this code. Seems that the list of cities is still changing while the for loop is running.

Comment: @Anonymous try now :) add time.sleep()]

Comment: Can you amend your code and confirm it solves the problem ?

Comment: @Anonymous amended try the new code

Comment: Added the gif also

Comment: Code work for me with `sleep`. Using Firefox on Linux.

Comment: @Anonymous now try by removing break

Answer (score 0):

The above postes is right.

Code like this is bound to fail because the page may be half-loaded (not all DOM elements will be loaded and ready).

You should ensure that the elements you are going to use are available.
This is normally done with `WebDriverWait`.

Another important module in Selenium is Expected conditions. Among the conditions is `staleness_of` which could be useful in your scenario.

If you combine `WebDriverWait` with `until` (*or* `until_not`) plus `expected_conditions` you should be able to achieve something eg:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.theselector')
WebDriverWait(driver=driver, timeout=10).until_not(EC.staleness_of(element))
```

**Warning**: note that in my code I am using `find_element_by_css_selector` and not `find_elements_by_css_selector` (plural).

References

- [Selenium waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)
- [Selenium Expected conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=expected#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)